# Pass `typing` object as parameter?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to write a function that takes two parameters: a variable, and a (non built-in) type.
I would like the type-check (using `mypy`) to fail if the type of the variable does not correspond to the type given as a second argument.

Here is a dummyfied example of what I tried:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
def do_something(variable: T, typeT: Type[T]) -> str:
    # Actually, I doing something here,
    # this return is for the sake of simplicity the example.
    return 'done'

MyNumberT = Tuple[float,int]
foo = (42.0, 42)
print(do_something(foo, MyNumberT))
```

On which `mypy` complains with the following: `error: Argument 2 to "do_something" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Type[Tuple[float, int]]"`.

I think I understand why it fails, after all:

```py
>>> type(Type[Tuple[float,int]])
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

So the second parameter is not of the hinted type.

But is there a way to make such a scenario work?

Comment: `Tuple[float,int]` is not a `Type`. It is a type annotation. Here, you need just `tuple`. What do you do with `typeT` in `do_something`?

Comment: Be aware that Python has no such thing as as "the type of ``(42.0, 42)``" – it only has "the type of ``(...)`` for all ``...``".